# cakephp complex queries

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How can I transform the **SQL** statement into the **CakePHP** Code? I am able to get the group by result. But how can I add the `inner Select Count(*)` statement?

I've updated the code under "Revised" However, I am getting this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INCOMPLETE' (T_STRING), expecting ')'. I am sure I check my open and close brackets.

SQL Statement below

```
SELECT 
    `id` , 
    `mtpToken` , 
    `mtpCreator_id` , 
    `school_id` , 
    `user_id` , 
    `mtpStatus` , 
    `created` , 
    `modified` , 
    (
        (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM mtpScreenings 
        WHERE (mtpStatus = 'INCOMPLETE' OR mtpStatus = 'HALFWAY') AND mtpToken = `mtpToken` )
    ) AS `mainStatus` 

    FROM `mtpScreenings` WHERE `mtpScreenings`.`school_id` = 15 GROUP BY `mtpToken`
```

CakePHP Code below

```
    $setting = $this->paginate = array(
        conditions' => array('MtpScreening.school_id' => 15),
        'recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => array('MtpScreening.field1'),
        'group' => array('MtpScreening.mtpToken'),
        'limit' => 1000
    );
```

Revised

```
    $setting = $this->paginate = array(
        conditions' => array('MtpScreening.school_id' => 15),
        'recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => array('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mtpScreenings 
        WHERE (mtpStatus = "INCOMPLETE" OR mtpStatus = "HALFWAY") AND mtpToken = `mtpToken`
    ) AS mainStatus'),
        'group' => array('MtpScreening.mtpToken'),
        'limit' => 1000
    );
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is the only difference here that virtual field you're creating in the subselect? If so, you can set it as a virtual field in the model you're querying, or you can define it as a custom field literally by cut and pasting the brackets and the `as mainStatus` part and pasting it as a field into your fields array

Comment: Try this [JOINING](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

Comment: @Manwal not necessary, a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) is built specifically for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Virtual Field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

Code example of virtual field:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
  'count' => "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM MtpScreening 
    WHERE (MtpScreening.mtpStatus = 'INCOMPLETE' OR MtpScreening.mtpStatus = 'HALFWAY') AND MtpScreening.mtpToken = 'mtpToken'"    
   );
```

This code will produce virtual field:

```
$this->find('all', array(
               'fields'=>array(
                        'MtpScreening.id',
                        'MtpScreening.mtpToken', 
                        'MtpScreening.mtpCreator_id', 
                        'MtpScreening.school_id',
                        'MtpScreening.count'/*virtual field*/
                       )
                )
           );
```

> **Pagination and virtual fields**
>
> Since virtual fields behave much like regular fields when doing
> find’s, Controller::paginate() will be
> able to sort by virtual fields too.

Comment: My revised code worked! just that i need to put double quotes instead of single quotes. Thank anyways!